# Extra '?' character generated in Chinese language in JSP after installing Weblogic 12

Tags: html, jsp, xslt

I usually use XSLT to transform XSL to JSP pages with no issues for all languages.

After a recent upgrade to Weblogic12 and Oracle Pack Eclipse, the problem occurred. It seems that using the JSP file in the Chinese language i have an additional '?' character on the right side of my buttons. Whereas in the English language i have an empty space instead of the usual &#160. current encoding is GBK. below is my code snippet.

Question: **what caused the end result after XSLT to appear as a '?' or ' ' instead of &#160 on the jsp page?**

recent changes to system that could cause: eclipse ganyemede to oracle pack eclipse, Java5 to Java6, weblogic to weblogic 12

```
        <a href="#" id="btn_NEWQUOTE" 
onclick="submitForm('/Controller/QUOTE','theForm'); 
    return (false);" class="actionBtn">
<span><span>NEW QUOTE</span></span></a>?>
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the exact code you use to declare the output encoding.